# max thread calls in specified seconds

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, numbers, call

I want to limit the number of calls for a method to 5 within 10 seconds. There will be calls to the method from different threads. After that time has passed, I want the counter for the method to be resetted so for the next 10 seconds, 5 more calls can be made and this will go on. What could be a good way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to happen if this limit is exceeded? Should throw an error or block? Is it okay to block for 10 second or more? e.g. if you have 11 threads waiting it will take at least 20 seconds to stay under your limit, assuming no new messages occur.

Comment: I want requests to wait for 3 seconds and then timeout if 10 seconds did not pass.

Comment: Do you want the calls to be evenly-spaced, or can they all come in a burst?

Comment: Also do you require that any range of 10 seconds only has 5 calls? ie) if on second 9 you make 5 calls, on second 11 are you allowed to make more calls?

Comment: Perhaps check out [Guava's `RateLimiter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html).

Comment: they don't have to be evenly spaced. it is not any range, there must be max 5 calss between 14:00:00 and 14:00:10 and, max 5 calls between 14:00:10 and 14:00:20

Comment: Do you want it to wait 3 seconds even if there is no chance the counter will be reset in 3 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use a [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) and a `Timer` to release tokens:

```
public class RateLimitedTask() {
    private final Timer timer = new Timer();
    private final Semaphore semaphore;
    private final Runnable task;

    public RateLimitedTask(
            final Runnable task, 
            final int limit, 
            final int delay
    ) {
        this.task = task;
        semaphore = new Semaphore(limit);

        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                semaphore.release(limit);
            }
        }, delay*1000, delay*1000);
    }

    public void run() throws InterruptedException {
        semaphore.acquire();
        task.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: @SaimDoruklu theres also a method `Semaphore#acquire` with a timeout you can use to throw an exception on the 3 second limit!